# why when adding path variable to the controller it blocks css and js

Tags: javascript, css, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using @PathVariable to obtain some placeholder from the uri 
this is the function from my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mail_detail/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showCourrierDetail(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    //System.out.println("id="+id);
    return "mail_detail";
}
```

It redirects me to jsp page named mail_detail 
My problem is that when I add the path variable, the jsp page don't read the css files although when I use

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mail_detail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public
 String showmail() {


    return "mail_detail";
}
```

It works and reads all the css files

Comment: can you tell me how your CSS `<link>` in your HTML looks like ?

Comment: they looks like this    `<link href="resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Ok. can you add a `/` before `resources` and check? It should look like - `<link href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: no,didn't work for me

Comment: I think the problem isn't from the jsp file because it works perfectly for me on the other controllers but I don't know why while using a controller with a variable path on it ,it shows me the page without loading css files

Comment: Just to clarify, the word `showCourrierDetail` has two `r`s in `Courrier`. Hope there is no typo here?

Comment: no,it's ok that doesn't matter

Comment: Yes, when i said add a `/`, i meant add that in the HTML not jsp page.

Comment: my jsp page contains the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your file is a jsp file you may prefix `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`in the URL, like `<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`.